# Preview files in finder without quicklook

Tags: macos, finder, preview

I'm a programmer and I use a lot of different file types that are all plain text.  I would like to view the contents of the files in finder, but not in QuickLook, rather in the right-most preview pane, like it does for standard text files.

[image: text displayed in preview pane]

I'd like the same thing for my codefiles (.scala, .html, .css, etc...)
[image: no test displayed in preview pane]

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/230204/make-os-xs-quick-look-work-for-custom-file-extensions does this help?

Comment: No I don't think so,  I'd like to view the file contents directly in finder - like the top screen shot, I don't want to open a new window.

Comment: Odd, maybe something is wrong with your setup due to other renderers. QLStephen works for me in 3-Panel view too (=> It has a Thumbnail hook too)

Comment: Sorry I don't know the technique, but I'll confirm it is possible. I turned on a bunch of text matchers last year somehow – now I see QuickLook and Finder pane previews for html, css, yaml, more. I'd be happy to look for breadcrumbs if you can confirm something to check.

Answer (score 1):

The plugin `qlstephen` does in fact show the content of text-based files in the preview pane, not only the QuickLook window.  What really threw me off was that the pop-up window & the pane embedded in finder are both called QuickLook.

Anyway, it's dead easy to install.  Download the latest version from here: https://github.com/whomwah/qlstephen/releases

Unzip

Copy the binary to the directory ~/Library/QuickLook  (create QuickLook if it doesn't already exist)